Icrawler unreliably downloading images
I am using icrawler on python to scrape images online. I have a list of strings download_waitlist = ["cat","dog","car","motorbike","snoop dogg"] that I want to download from the internet using icrawler.
There are two issues with the package: sometimes it ends the process without having downloaded anything, meaning that there are no images in my download folder. It also simply doesn't download the right images.
I often have way too many cat images that end up getting labeled as "dog" or "car". Any workarounds, anything I am doing wrong?
Here is my downloader code:
download_waitlist = ["cat","dog","car","motorbike","snoop dogg"]
AllImages = {}
google_crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(storage={"root_dir": "Downloads"}, feeder_threads=3, parser_threads=3, downloader_threads=3)

def getfilepath(offset,imgformat,dotslash): # this returns a string with the correct file path for any image number
    if len(str(offset))>5:
        gotnumber = str(offset)
    else:
        gotnumber = str(0)
        for i in range(5-len(str(offset))):
            gotnumber = gotnumber+str(0)
        gotnumber = gotnumber+str(offset)
    gotnumber = "Downloads/"+gotnumber+"."+imgformat
    if dotslash:
        gotnumber = "./"+gotnumber
    return(gotnumber)

for iteration, query in enumerate(download_waitlist): #downloading the list
    search = query
    offset = iteration*10 #making sure images don't override each other
    google_crawler.crawl(keyword=search, max_num=2, file_idx_offset=offset) #searching for 2 images

    if os.path.isfile(getfilepath(offset+1,"jpg",True)): #loading the image using pygame
        loaded = pygame.image.load(getfilepath(offset+1,"jpg",False))
    elif os.path.isfile(getfilepath(offset+1,"png",False)):
        loaded = pygame.image.load(getfilepath(offset+1,"png",False))
    AllImages[search] = loaded #adding and labeling the image in my dictionary
    print("downloaded "+str(iteration+1)+"/"+str(len(download_waitlist))+" images")

I tried downloading https://github.com/Patty-OFurniture/icrawler.git which has been modified to fix reliability issues but couldn't get it to work on my instance.
